# Remix Run + React Framework: Form submission is blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

Have been trying to test out the Remix JS framework's form submission and cannot seem to get it to work. I must be missing something obvious, but have been staring at it for hours and haven't been able to find it:

Below is a screenshot of what I'm seeing... I've got a very simple form that has one input text field called "name". When I submit it, I can see that the Form Data includes `name: test`, but then on my server logs, I see FormData {} when I do `console.log(body)`.

Does anyone know why there is this inconsistency?

[image: What I'm seeing]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Instead, post your code as text wrapped in a code block or stack snippet

Comment: Apologies! Needed to grab the screenshot of the network transaction + code + browser.

Comment: Yeah, the left part of the image is totally fine. But it would be good to just use that half and post the code from the right part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.formData()` returns a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

You need to use getters such as get() or getAll().

```js
export async function action({ request }: ActionArgs) {
    const form = await request.formData()
    const name = form.get('name')
    console.log(name)

    return json({ status: 'success' })
}
```

If you see the [Remix docs on action](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/route/action), you can see they use `body.get('title')` to get the title field from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ❌

```
console.log(formData)
```

Do ✅

```
console.log(formData.get("inputName"))
```

[Reference](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/3616)